# Does the Buckingham Pi theorem depend on rank, or quantity of units?

Tags: mathematical-modeling, applications, dimensional-analysis

Does the Buckingham PI theorem require that `k` be the rank of the dimensional matrix or is it the quantity of base units; given `p=n-k`, where `k = fundamental dimensions` and `n = dimensions of the variables`?

For example, in a dimensional analysis of `f(a,b,c)` with unit system `M,L,T`, where `[a]=MLT` `[b]=ML` `[c]=T`, does `k=3` (because M,L,T) or `k=2` (because the rank is 2)?

Additionally, if it is true that `k = rank of dimensional matrix`, should a variable be eliminated so that `k = rank of dimensional matrix = # of input variables`? Is this how the rule of independent variables is enforced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You answer your own question in the third paragraph, the rank is equal to the number of physical *dimensions*, not units.

In your example, the matrix is
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0\\ 1&0&1 \end{pmatrix}$$
(where columns refer to a,b,c and rows to ML and T) which is of rank 2.

M and L are not independent dimensions, with the variables a,b,c you can never get M or L alone. It is as if you are in 3D space but you only have the 2D subspace spanned by (1,1,0) and (0,0,1).

Anyway, the "number of units" is ill defined, because you can usually express any unit in terms of a different number of other units (e.g., 1 sec = 1 Coulomb / 1 Ampère).

So yes, in some sense you "eliminate" variables whose units can be expressed in terms of others - rather than to introduce a new variable. Here you have [a] = MLT = [b][c], so you can "drop" (the units of) a.
You can do that by Gaussian elimination on the matrix where you can first write all units individually: e.g., starting with rows M,L,T, you'd have
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0\\1 & 1 & 0\\ 1&0&1 \end{pmatrix}$$
Then you eliminate e.g. row 2 (doing R2 <- R2 - R1), and if you discard the empty row, you get the previous matrix. You can track the combinations used by including a unit matrix to the right (but you don't consider that for the rank).

Comment: Can you please expand on what you mean by "track the combinations"? I think that your hinting at something that I am interested in but not fully grasping.

Comment: Well, I mean to *find* "the" (actually not unique, so rather "a") set of "independent" combinations of units. It's like finding a base of a vector space spanned by a set of not linearly independent vectors. You use the Gaussian elimination procedure to "triangularize" the matrix so that the remaining (nonzero) rows (or cols) are independent and form a base. You can do exactly the same here, vectors (a,b,c) corresponding to combinations(products) of units (M^a L^b T^c, etc).